# Rails - Is there a shortcut to pass all existing params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can you pass **all parameters** to a controller action?

```
# instead of:
<%= link_to mylist_url(id: params[:id], se: "true", st: params[:st], re: params[:re], li: params[:li]) do %> ... <% end %>

# something like:
<% link_to mylist_url(params: :all, se: "true") do %> ... <% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you just use [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002880)?, something like:

```
<% link_to mylist_url(params.merge(:se=>"true")) do %> ... <% end %>
```

Comment: That will include `:controller` and `:action`, making them show up in the URL query string.