# Add fields to the params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I am trying to pass a value from a view to the controller. The user is submitting a form, and I want to pass a hidden value which is not related to the form itself. So my question is: how can I manually add entries to the params hash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `params.merge`.

See docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000759

A similar question: [Rails - Is there a shortcut to pass all existing params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112425/rails-is-there-a-shortcut-to-pass-all-existing-params)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for, since I tried to pass a value without link_to. The simple answer was a hidden_field_tag and pass the value into redirect_to.